# How do you load a Store in ExtJS from an Oracle Application Express backend

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, oracle-apex

I am attempting to load data into an ExtJS v4.2.1 store from an APEX backend via AJAX.

Using ApEx's `htmldb_Get` function, I am able to call an Application Process which interacts with the database and returns/modifies data accordingly.

However when trying to load this data into an ExtJS store, things get a bit tricky.

My store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('DocumentEditor.store.Nodes', {
    alias: 'store.Nodes',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'DocumentEditor.proxy.Ajax',
        'DocumentEditor.model.Node'
    ],

    storeId: 'Nodes',

    model: 'DocumentEditor.model.Node',

    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    remoteGroup: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        url: '/clms/wwv_flow.show/',

        format: 'json',

        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        },

        extraParams: {
            'p_request': 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=MY_PROCESS',
            'p_instance': INSTANCE,
            'p_flow_id': FLOW,
            'p_flow_step_id': FLOW_STEP
        },

        noCache: false,

        limitParam: 'max',
        startParam: 'offset',
        sortParam: 'sortorder',

        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            totalProperty: 'count'
        }
    }
});
```

Executing this:

```
var x = Ext.create('DocumentEditor.store.Nodes');
x.load();
```

Generates this POST:

[image: POST 1]

And I get this response from APEX:

> Error
>
> ERR-7620: Could not determine workspace for application (200).
>
> Expecting p_company or wwv_flow_company cookie to contain security group id of application
>   owner.

But executing this:

```
var x = new htmldb_Get(null, APP_ID, 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=MY_PROCESS', PAGE_ID);
x.GetAsync(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Generates this POST:

[image: POST 2]

And the response I would expect.

### My question:

1) How do I get `htmldb_Get` functionality within an ExtJS Ajax Proxy to enable me to retrieve data?  (Or how can I populate a store with data from Apex?)

2) How can the first POST respond with a `404: Not Found`, while the second (identical, to the exact same URL) responds with `200: OK`?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Stupid guess: can you try without the trailing slash of `wwv_flow.show` ?

Comment: what is your sql query?

Comment: What would help tremendously is a screenshot of the POST tab. Are the params `p_instance, p_flow_id and p_flow_step_id` actually filled with a value, because from your sample I'd say they're not.

Comment: @Tom I have triple checked, and all variables have accurate values (I can see them under the "Post" tab in Firebug, and output to the console immediately before the request)